# How would I approach writing a function for the volume of this rectangular prism inscribed in a rectangular pyramid?

Tags: geometry

[image]

Hi all,

The answer is supposed to be v(x)=x(20-2x)^2.
I don't understand how to derive the (20-2x) in this equation.
Can anyone explain where this comes from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. The top plane of the prism creates a pyramid similar to the whole pyramid. You can find the height of that pyramid and then the side of its square base.

Comment: Thanks so much! I understand the problem now